# Adding and Opening links on a JButton

Tags: java, swing

I am coding a simple JFrame/Application that opens an applet with some simple buttons on them.
I would just like those buttons to open certain webpages/links on click.

Code:

```
package me.jamplifier;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Launcher extends JFrame
{
    public Launcher()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hurricane Craft");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Welcome to Hurricane Craft");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(label);

        JButton site = new JButton("Site");
        JButton forums = new JButton("Forums");
        panel.add(site);
        panel.add(forums);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Launcher();
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking for help with? The creation of the 'onClick' code? Or how to actually open a link in Java?

Answer (score 2):

You can open a webpage from java by using the following code, it will open your default browser and use the string/url provided:

```
public void openWebPage(String url){
   try {         
     java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(url));
   }
   catch (java.io.IOException e) {
       System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   }
}
```

To let this be called by your buttons, simply add an [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) for both your site and forum button as such:

```
forum.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        openWebPage("http://www.mywebsite.com/forum/");
    }
});
```

Make another actionlistener for your site with the site instead of the forum url, and you are done!

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `ActionListener` to your buttons that opens a webpage like this:

```
JButton site = new JButton("Site");
site.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse("http://www.mysite.com");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the above code you are giving bring error on the .browse command saying "method browse(URI) in the type Desktop is not applicable for the arguments (String)"
To fix the error create a function/method that will take a string parameter the call the above function in the event Listener Action performed button.

```
public void createLink(String url){
       try {         
         java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(url));
       }
       catch (java.io.IOException e) {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
    }
```

Call the method like this.

```
public void createLink(ActionEvent e) {
            openWebPage("https://studentportal.mmu.ac.ke/");
            
        }
```